# Enums with inherited functionality

Tags: java, inheritance, enums

I have the following Enum constants for real life equipment:

```
HELMET,
CHESTPIECE,
BOOTS,
SWORD,
MACE,
HAMMER,
SHIELD,
BOW,
CROSSBOW,
STAFF
...;
```

I have another class called `Battle` which dictates what equipment can be used in that specific battle. For example:

`new Battle(Equipment.HAMMER, Equipment.SHIELD, EQUIPMENT.BOW);`

Which means that only Hammers, Shields, or Bows can be used.

Now I expanded on that and have the need for sub categories. For example:

`new Battle(Equipment.SHIELD, Equipment.Weapons.values())`

Which is equivalent to saying:

`new Battle(Equipment.SHIELD, Equipment.SWORD, Equipment.MACE, Equipment.HAMMER, ...)` etc

Which also means that `new Battle(Equipment.values())` should yield every enum value

Since `Enum`s are final, I tried the following:

```
public interface Equipment { }

public enum MeleeWeapon implements Equipment
{
    SWORD,
    MACE,
    HAMMER,
    STAFF, ...;
}

public enum RangedWeapon implements Equipment
{
    BOW, CROSSBOW;
}

...
```

But with this, I'm unable to say `Equipment.Weapon.values() // get all weapons, ranged and melee`. There's no sense of inherited relationships between classes, and I also lose everything that is not defined in the interface. It doesn't feel like a good solution here.

I tried making regular classes:

```
public abstract class Equipment
{
    private static Set<Equipment> instances = new HashSet<>();

    public static Set<Equipment> values()
    {
        return instances;
    }

    public Equipment()
    {
        instances.add(this);
    }
}

public abstract class Weapon extends Equipment
{
    private static Set<Weapon> instances = new HashSet<>();

    public static Set<Weapon> values()
    {
        return instances;
    }

    public Weapon()
    {
        super() // explicit call
        instances.add(this);
    }
}

public class MeleeWeapon extends Weapon
{
    private static Set<MeleeWeapon> instances = new HashSet<>();

    public static final MeleeWeapon SWORD = new MeleeWeapon();
    public static final MeleeWeapon MACE = new MeleeWeapon();
    ...

    public static Set<MeleeWeapon> values()
    {
        return instances;
    }

    public MeleeWeapon()
    {
        super() // explicit call
        instances.add(this);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately there is a ton of repeated code, heavy on memory, and also `public static Set<Weapon> values()` causes a compile error because it attempts to override `values()` in the superclass with a different return type. I was able to solve this with generics (`<? extends Weapon>`) but it's still an awful solution.

What is the right approach here? I need inheritance with my enum values but I cannot find a way how to do so.

Comment: Is this Java code? If yes you should add the `java` tag.

Comment: I don't really get why you need inheritance. It seems you just need various sets (or arrays, eek!) of enums. Why don't you just add a static weapons() method in your Equipment enum, returning all weapons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Still keeping the enum usage, it is possible to associate each element of the enumeration with the groups to which it belongs and then return filtered groups of elements in dedicated methods.

We'll need another - smaller - enum which enumerates the properties to filter on, for example:

```
public enum EquipmentType {

  WEAPON, ARMOR, TOOL, CLOTHING;

}
```

The elements of the enumeration are associated with their respective groups:

```
public enum Equipment {

  HELMET(ARMOR),
  CHESTPIECE(ARMOR),
  BOOTS(ARMOR, CLOTHING),
  SWORD(WEAPON),
  MACE(WEAPON),
  HAMMER(WEAPON, TOOL),
  SHIELD(ARMOR),
  BOW(WEAPON),
  CROSSBOW(WEAPON),
  STAFF(WEAPON);

  private final Set<EquipmentType> types;

  Equipment(EquipmentType... eqTypes) {
    this.types = Arrays.stream(eqTypes)
                       .collect(Collectors.toSet());
  }

  // common filtering method
  private static List<Equipment> filterByType(EquipmentType type) {
    return Arrays.stream(values())
        .filter(eq -> eq.types.contains(type))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  // dedicated methods for each group of items
  public static List<Equipment> getWeapons() {
    return filterByType(WEAPON);
  }

  public static List<Equipment> getArmor() {
    return filterByType(ARMOR);
  }

}
```

There is still no inheritance or more evolved typing involved in this approach and I think it would be better to avoid using the enum at all if you want more flexibility.

Comment: This is definitely not bad but I thought there was a better solution utilizing inheritance or interfaces. This felt like I was hard-coding a solution, since for example `MACE`, `SWORD`, `HAMMER`, have to be repeated twice. I hoped there would be a way so that when I define `MACE`, it can understand that it is a `MeleeWeapon`, which is also a `Weapon`, which is also an `Equipment`.

Comment: @Hatefiend Enums can have a state. You can add a type field to your enum, and return all enum instances of a given type from the methods.

Comment: @Antot Okay I understand. Still not the most graceful approach but it works. Thanks for the help.